# TYPO3 addToolbarItem (BE extension)

Tags: typo3, typo3-4.5, typo3-extensions

Hey guys and Happy Easter,

I am working on an extension for the backend and would like to have the standard toolbar with save and cancel options in my own extension.
So I would like to have sth. like this:
[image: typo3-stackoverflow-backend-addtoolbaritem]

I am kind of an newbie and would like to have a little more detailed answer. 
Found something about `addToolbarItem` on the internet but don't know how to use it.

**Edit:** 
Unfortunately I have to work with TYPO3 v4.5 and ***pibase*** extension and don't have enough time to change the version to 6.2.9...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***Assuming you're using TYPO 6.x+ and Extbase!***

You can put additional elements from your view to the layout by additional **sections**. most probably your view now looks like:

```
<f:layout name="Default"/>

<f:section name="content">
    <h1>Foo</h1>
</f:section>
```

so add new section i.e.:

```
<f:layout name="Default"/>

<f:section name="myButtons">
    <f:be.buttons.icon icon="actions-document-new" title="Create new Foo" />
</f:section>

<f:section name="content">
    <h1>Foo</h1>
</f:section>
```

And finally in your **Default.html** layout render your section in proper place (set it as optional, otherwise you'll get an exception if missing!)

```
....
<div class="typo3-docheader-buttons">
    <div class="left">
        <f:render section="myButtons" optional="true"/>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <a href="javascript:location.reload(true);"><span title="Reload" class="t3-icon t3-icon-actions t3-icon-actions-system t3-icon-system-refresh">&nbsp;</span></a>
        <f:be.buttons.shortcut />
    </div>
</div>
....
```

Of course this way you can also set other elements like `<f:be.menus.actionMenu>`, `<f:be.pageInfo />` etc, or even just your text labels.

Check ViewHelpers in `typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/Be/` for some ready to use elements.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I don't have a default.html or any html at all just a index.php where I include other php files (I have to work to work on an existing extension for my work) Typo 3 v4.5.x

Comment: Edit your question then and add these infos (about version) it's important as almost nobody uses old school PI way nowadays. Also try to switch to TYPO3 6.x+ ASAP - especially if you plan to extend your extensions in the future! Working with Extbase is definitely nicer approach for both FE plugins and BE modules. Also you can create Extbase extensions also within TYPO 4.5+ anyway that would be better to follow the latest stable TYPO3.  Unfortunately I cannot help you now as I don't remember where did I use PI for BE last time... it was for sure many years ago.